# MMIO, PMIO, mmap, memory-mapped file, DMA, I/O bus, I/O channel

Tags: linux, file-io, io, linux-kernel, channel

As I study I/O operations on Linux, I am kinda confused of its terminology.

There are several words that are related to I/Os

1. Memory Mapped IO (MMIO)
2. Port Mapped IO (PMIO)
3. mmap()
4. memory-mapped file
5. DMA
6. I/O Bus
7. I/O Channel

To my knowledge,

1. MMIO is not separating I/O space from main memory area
2. PMIO is having special ports numbers for I/O access
3. mmap is creating a new virtual memory mapping
4. memory-mapped file is mapping some range of data on a storage device to main memory to reduce the frequency of I/O system calls.
5. DMA is making it possible to transfer data from a storage device to main memory without CPUs.

Here,

1) What are the differences between MMIO and memory-mapped file?

2) What are the examples of MMIO and PMIO?

3) Which are I/Os that are performed through DMA and SATA interface, MMIO or PMIO? If both are wrong, what are the I/Os called?

4) For a keyboard and mouse, which one is used? MMIO, PMIO?

5) What are I/O bus and I/O channel? and Please explain their differences using real examples like?

6) Is I/O Channel same as DMA?

7) Are SATA, PCIe I/O Bus?

There are a lot of questions.

I would be very happy to discuss it.

Thank you.

Comment: 1) They are orthogonal, nothing in common. 2) Not all architectures have IO ports. The difference is assembly commands and actual signals on wires inside or outside SoC/CPU chip. DMA can't do IO by the definition. 4) Depends on the driver, architecture and so on. 5) Just some terms. 6) Quite likely not at all. 7) It's not clear what you imply under "I/O bus". I have no idea if this term has one meaning.

Comment: This question is too broad. I would vote to close.

Comment: Please shorten your question. I understand your confusion, I'd like to help, but noone will read a question this generic and broad.